What authorisation would I need to disclose information from a dead friend's computer?
A friend of mine is an accountant, and we have an informal arrangement that I help him with computer problems and he slips me some beer money in return. No formal arrangement or contract has ever agreed between us. I am a retired network manager so this is easy work for me and ... well ... beer is good :-)
My friend has recently been diagnosed with cancer and the prognosis isn't great. If he does not manage to tidy up his affairs I imagine his clients will be eager to recover their data (sometimes many years worth of data) from his server so they can give it to whoever takes over their account. And since I know the administrator password for his server I can foresee them approaching me.
I obviously cannot just hand out data to anyone who asks, but who would authorise me to hand over any data? His executor? His heirs? As far as I know I have no legal obligation to do anything so I could just walk away, but it's natural to want to help where I can. I just don't want to get in trouble for doing it.
In an ideal world my friend would make some arrangement but right now he has other concerns and I'm reluctant to press him with questions about what to do when he's dead!
(I have no idea how to tag this. If anyone more knowledgeable would like to edit in appropriate tags please go ahead.)
More information
quarague suggests in their answer that my friend's business will be a company, and this is indeed the case (though as far as I know he is its only employee). I found his business on the Companies House web site and it is described as Company type: Private limited Company.
Footnote
Just for clarity, I am not asking what I should do. The rational thing to do would be to walk away, which is what I will do unless I can be sure about my legal position.
I am asking the question in the title:

What authorisation would I need to disclose information from a dead friend's computer?


I know you're trying to be nice, but I think you really should bring this up with him. He may already be thinking about it: Any responsible CEO makes succession plans.

Why wouldn't your accountant friend have already passed everything his clients need to know? My own accountant sends me his computations, summaries and statements and the tax returns submitted on my behalf. His own files are confidential.

@WeatherVane Clients may want the computer files to avoid re-keying years of information. The files may contain source information, like receipts, that are kept only for audit purposes. The files may contain information, like change logs, that may be needed as part of an investigation, e.g. to show numbers weren't manipulated to cook the books.

@user71659 I see: a client may have handed over a box of original receipts etc. and said 'sort this lot out'. The accountant may have done the 'books' too.

@Barmar I take your point but (a) it's not that simple - there is an element of denial involved - and (b) I'm cautious about getting too involved.

If you've been his "computer guy" for years, you might already be too involved. But the alternative is to just assume he knows what he's doing, and it's not your problem. Since you have no legal responsibility, this may be a better question for [interpersonal.se].

If your friend was in accounting, this must have been organised as some kind of business and someone has to legally take over that business. It is part of the inheritance so someone from the heirs. That is the person you need to talk to, you give them access to all the data on computers and then they have to decide what to do with it and pass it on to the customers of the business where appropriate.

Aha, thanks, yes my friend's business is a private limited company - see the update to my question. So I can act if and only if whoever inherits the company instructs me to.

You must do what your contract says you must do
Don’t think you have a contract? Wrong. Services for beer - that’s a contract (and probably a tax violation if you didn’t declare it to HMR&C).
It would appear that the contract is silent on what you should do if the director of the company ceases to give you instructions. So you should do nothing.
Upon the death of the director, the company will appoint a new director(s) or an administrator/liquidator to wind it up. Then you can take instructions from them.
On no account should you take instructions from someone you don’t have a contract with.
Also, since this is an accountancy practice, you will have a lot of access to a lot of personal data. I hope you and they have fulfilled your GDPR obligations.

I doubt there was really a formal "service for beer" arrangement. It sounds more like they each do favors for each other: one fixes computer problems, the other pays the tab when they go to the pub.

@Barmar contracts don’t need to be “formal”. Any quid-pro-quo arrangement like this is almost surely a contract.

I'm not sure it's even a "quid pro quo". If you invite me to dinner this week, and I return the favor next week, is that a quid pro quo or just normal friendly behavior?

@Barmar there is a difference between a social arrangement and a commercial one - the latter are presumed to be contracts. We’re talking about IT services for a business here, not dinner arrangements.

Actually, I misread the OP. Where they wrote "slipped me beer money", I interpreted it as paying when they went out together socially, rather than actually giving him money. So I thought it was more of a social arrangement of swapping favors.
